# Mimicking the Clone trait in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust

I have a simple linked list type and an implementation of `Clone` for
it:

```
#[deriving(Show)]
enum List {
    Cons(int, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

impl Clone for List {
    fn clone(&self) -> List {
        match *self {
            Cons(val, ref rest) => Cons(val, rest.clone()),
            Nil => Nil,
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected. But if I make my own `MyClone` trait with
[the same signature](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/clone/trait.Clone.html)
as that of `Clone`, I get an error:

```
trait MyClone {
    fn my_clone(&self) -> Self;
}

impl MyClone for List {
    fn my_clone(&self) -> List {
        match *self {
            Cons(val, ref rest) => Cons(val, rest.my_clone()),
            Nil => Nil,
        }
    }
}

.../src/main.rs:23:46: 23:61 error: mismatched types: expected `Box<List>`, found `List` (expected box, found enum List)
.../src/main.rs:23             Cons(val, ref rest) => Cons(val, rest.my_clone()),
```

It works fine if I change it to `box rest.my_clone()`, but I don't
understand why. The `MyClone` and `Clone` traits are the same, so it
seems to me they would accept the same implementation.

(I'm compiling with rustc 0.12.0-nightly (72841b128 2014-09-21 20:00:29 +0000).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because rust also has an implementation of Clone for `Box<T>`. If you implement `MyClone` for it, it will owrk at expected.

```
#[deriving(Show)]
enum List {
    Cons(int, Box<List>),
    Nil,
}

trait MyClone {
    fn my_clone(&self) -> Self;
}

impl<T: MyClone> MyClone for Box<T> {
    fn my_clone(&self) -> Box<T> {
        self.my_clone()
    }
}

impl MyClone for List {
    fn my_clone(&self) -> List {
        match *self {
            Cons(val, ref rest) => Cons(val, rest.my_clone()),
            Nil => Nil,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. For future readers, here's the [implementation in standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/72841b128df8b6a4eb88b1048548e2eec5244449/src/liballoc/boxed.rs#L51).